# How to draw proper chart of distributional tree?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am using python with matplotlib and need to visualize distribution percentage of sub-groups of an data set.

imagine this tree:

```
Data --- group1 (40%)
     -
     --- group2 (25%)
     -
     --- group3 (35%)


group1 --- A (25%)
       -
       --- B (25%)
       -
       --- c (50%)
```

and it can go on, each group can have several sub-groups and same for each sub group.

How can i plot a proper chart for this info?

Comment: I have problem with matplotlib, if someone is familiar with it and have experience working with it, then he/she is qualified to answer my question. I know how this site works.
thanks!

Comment: No, I didn't judge your qualifications, what I meant was comment/answer contents that help the situation, otherwise don't bother. the question is clear and specific. I wanted to draw a chart with matplotlib. if you know the solution you are more than welcome to post Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a minimal reproducible example that I think fits your description, but please let me know if that is not what you need.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
n_rows = 100
data['group'] = np.random.choice(['1', '2', '3'], n_rows)
data['subgroup'] = np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], n_rows)
```

For instance, we could get the following counts for the subgroups.

```
In [1]: data.groupby(['group'])['subgroup'].value_counts()
Out[1]: group  subgroup
    1   A      17
        C      16
        B      5
    2   A      23
        C      10
        B      7
    3   C      8
        A      7
        B      7
 Name: subgroup, dtype: int64
```

I created a function that computes the necessary counts given an ordering of the columns (e.g. `['group', 'subgroup']`) and incrementally plots the bars with the corresponding percentages.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm

def plot_tree(data, ordering, axis=False):
    """
    Plots a sequence of bar plots reflecting how the data 
    is distributed at different levels. The order of the 
    levels is given by the ordering parameter.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data: pandas DataFrame
    ordering: list
        Names of the columns to be plotted.They should be 
        ordered top down, from the larger to the smaller group.
    axis: boolean
        Whether to plot the axis.

    Returns
    -------
    fig: matplotlib figure object.
        The final tree plot.
    """

    # Frame set-up
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9.2, 3*len(ordering)))
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-1, len(ordering)) + 0.5)
    ax.set_xticklabels(['All'] + ordering, fontsize=18)
    if not axis:
        plt.axis('off')
    counts=[data.shape[0]]

    # Get colormap
    labels = ['All']
    for o in reversed(ordering):
        labels.extend(data[o].unique().tolist())
    # Pastel is nice but has few colors. Change for a larger map if needed
    cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Pastel1', len(labels))
    colors = dict(zip(labels, [cmap(i) for i in range(len(labels))]))

    # Group the counts
    counts = data.groupby(ordering).size().reset_index(name='c_' + ordering[-1])
    for i, o in enumerate(ordering[:-1], 1):
        if ordering[:i]:
            counts['c_' + o]=counts.groupby(ordering[:i]).transform('sum')['c_' + ordering[-1]]
    # Calculate percentages
    counts['p_' + ordering[0]] = counts['c_' + ordering[0]]/data.shape[0]
    for i, o in enumerate(ordering[1:], 1):
        counts['p_' + o] = counts['c_' + o]/counts['c_' + ordering[i-1]]

    # Plot first bar - all data
    ax.bar(-1, data.shape[0], width=1, label='All', color=colors['All'], align="edge")
    ax.annotate('All -- 100%', (-0.9, 0.5), fontsize=12)
    comb = 1  # keeps track of the number of possible combinations at each level
    for bar, col in enumerate(ordering):
        labels = sorted(data[col].unique())*comb
        comb *= len(data[col].unique())
        # Get only the relevant counts at this level
        local_counts = counts[ordering[:bar+1] + 
                              ['c_' + o for o in ordering[:bar+1]] + 
                              ['p_' + o for o in ordering[:bar+1]]].drop_duplicates()
        sizes = local_counts['c_' + col]
        percs = local_counts['p_' + col]
        bottom = 0  # start at from 0
        for size, perc, label in zip(sizes, percs, labels):
            ax.bar(bar, size, width=1, bottom=bottom, label=label, color=colors[label], align="edge")
            ax.annotate('{} -- {:.0%}'.format(label, perc), (bar+0.1, bottom+0.5), fontsize=12)
            bottom += size  # stack the bars
    ax.legend(colors)
    return fig
```

With the data shown above we would get the following.

```
fig = plot_tree(data, ['group', 'subgroup'], axis=True)
```

[image: Tree plot example]

Comment: I wanted to thank you in advance, but it's not exactly what I meant. I wanted single bar/square, with value of 100% for Data (in my example tree), then group1, group2, group3 as 3 bars stacked on top of each other with mentioned percentage (40%,25%.35%) inside Data bar. then each group divide to subgroups with their own percentage info and goes on. I tried to draw stack bar myself but I couldn't push bars into each other, they just stacked on top of each other.

Comment: @Ali Crash, I'm not sure if I completely understood what you're looking for, but I gave it another try. See my updated answer.

Comment: it was not exactly what I had in mind, but it suits as well. I've reached to decision that matplotlib is not a right tool for my purpose. frontend tools like d3.js is more helpful in these situations. 
Thank you.

Comment: the legend is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stacked bar graph?

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py

Comment: yes i tied it , stacked bar graph generally doesn't fit my purpose, because it stacked info on top of each other, for example data is 100, group1 is 40, when you plot them together, the new bars max is 140, I want group1 plot inside Data, not on top of data.

Comment: but you have to use your values on the groups level - plot just groups - in total they will give you the aggregated value of the whole data

Comment: if you think you have solution, you are more than welcome to post an Answer, I played lot around stacked bar chart and couldn't get any progress.